# use wavelet transform to analyze signal

Tags: signal-processing

let us suppose that we have following signal

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 %plot(x)
end
```

and i want to get   it's spectral structure using wavelet transform,which wavelet transform should i use and  which parameters?i meant scale and delay parameter?i generated signal by this command and get vector  $y$ with length

`$y=generate1(3,500,2)$;

```
length(y)

ans =

   501
```

now about  wavelet transform,of course i can use a lot of  wavelet  basis fucntions,but which one is suitable for this case?thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't it depend on which features you want to analyze/detect/classify?

Comment: i want to find  frequencies and  as fourier transform or   windowed fourier transform do

Comment: Since your signals occupy the entire time window and do not change frequency, you don't need any time resolution. So I am not sure that a wavelet transform has anything to offer. In any case, you can try a [Morlet wavelet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlet_wavelet) optimized for frequency resolution. The linked page describes it.

Comment: thanks for hint,you are welcome :)